# Copy files over network with a specific name (or the most recent one)

Tags: powershell, command-line, command, command-prompt, powershell-3.0

I have to copy my SQL Server backup files daily over network. For this I'm thinking about writing a batch file or a powershell script and run it as a scheduled task.
A problem in this process would be to distinguish the most recent file for a particular database as three days of backups for the same database are kept in the source directory. The naming convention is:    databaseName_backup_yyyy_mm_dd_hhmmss.bak
For example, there would be these three files under the source directory for the database myDatabase:
myDatabase_backup_2015_03_19_230000.bak
myDatabase_backup_2015_03_20_230000.bak
myDatabase_backup_2015_03_21_230000.bak

The file would either be the most recent created one for one particular database or the one whose name includes the current date as per above.

Thank you all.

Edit: I can implement this on the target server, not on the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this, without much clever Powershell logic, borrowing traditional CMDs, as SQL is handling your retention (3 full backups by the looks of it) i do the following. Run via task scheduler on the server where your storing these SQL backups (so they PULL rather than get sent from SQL)

```
$remoteserver = "servername"
$remoteshare = "backups$"

$toEmail = "something@something.com"
$subject = "$remoteserver Robocopy Log"
$fromEmail = "anemail@domain.com"
$smtpServer = "exchange.local"
$Attachment = "C:\scripts\$remoteserver-copy.log"


robocopy "$remoteshare\$remoteserver\" G:\LocalDestination\"$remoteserver"\ /s | Out-File $Attachment
Send-MailMessage $toEmail $subject -SmtpServer $smtpServer -From $fromEmail -Attachment $Attachment
```

`

Comment: Thanks but I can't send big size backups via smtp. I need to copy the files over.

Comment: Robocopy is doing the copying, the email is just the Robocopy log so you can review for any problems / confirmation of successful backup. You can comment out the email part if needed, but for me, confirmation is the most important piece.

Comment: Thanks man. Would you mind modifying this script so that I can run from the destination server? (The server where the backups of backups will be stored.)

Comment: Thats exactly how its setup, it pulls from your SQL servers. Where `$remoteserver = "SQLSERVER01"` and `$remoteshare = "backups$"` (or whatever, they are just examples). The account the script is running as (in Task Scheduler) will need NTFS permissions on that file share.